# ng-csv with data from api calls

Tags: angularjs

I need to assign data to ng-csv from api call.
I tried this. but didn't worked

```
script:
$scope.getArray = function () {

    var temp;
    $http.get(Config.serviceUrlBase + '/abc/ExportToCSV').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
       temp = data;
    })
   return temp;
};
 //here data is string separated by comma and new line for csv format.

aspx file:
<Button ID="ExportToCSV" ng-csv="getArray" filename="test.csv" lazy-load="true"
>ExportToCSV</Button>
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 10):

The `temp` variable is assigned to asynchronously, which means that `return temp;` actually returns `undefined`.

The `ng-csv` attribute accepts promises, so you should use `$q`:

```
$scope.getArray = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http
        .get(Config.serviceUrlBase + '/abc/ExportToCSV')
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
           deferred.resolve(data);
        });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Note: `$q` is a service that you can inject in your controller or wherever it is you can inject things.

Comment: Tried this. Data is have value like "abc,xyz,trv". But csv file is giving only one value i.e 0(zero)

Answer (score 6):

You are missing '**()**'.

ng-csv="**getArray()**"

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue and it's solved by the following:

```
$scope.getArray = function () {

   var temp = $http.get(Config.serviceUrlBase + '/abc/ExportToCSV').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      return data;
   })
   return temp;
};
```

The issue was because temp variable by default is `undefined`. So, You should wait till the variable has returned value from promise.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this you need to use a promise with your lazy load, but you must also include the resolved response as an array as your data is in JSON format.

Leaving the response in JSON format led to 0 being loaded only under the first column when we had a collection being returned.

In the below AngularJS example we had a collection we wanted to store in the array (i.e. rows of data):

```
$scope.getArray = function() {
    var deferme = $q.defer();

    $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
        var myArr = [];

        for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
            myArr.push([data[i].value1, data[i].value2, etc...]);
        }

        deferme.resolve(myArr);     
    });

    return deferme.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the value of the `ng-csv` directive should be an expression, a value or a promise.

So you can assign `$scope.getArray`

```
myapp.controller('myctrl', function ($scope) {
    $http.get(url)
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.getArray = data;
            });
});
```

AngularJS is watching for scope variable to be updated.